# Can we run docker in swarm mode with two stack files on same server? If yes then how

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We have many applications & we have grouped them into two based on their interdependence. We have configured the Docker which runs in SWARM mode with all these applications.
As there are about 29 applications running, updating stack file for any application becomes critical & many time people are overriding others change.

We want to keep two stack files which should run on same server in swarm mode.
So first question is - Is it possible? 
I yes, then can anyone help as how this can be configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer but forgot to post.
One can have as many as stack files e.g. group1-stack.yml, group2-stack.yml, ...
(Files can have any name)
These files are used only when file is referred in performing some operations on stack e.g.

```
docker stack deploy -c <fileName> <stackname>
```

So, one can group all related apps in as many as stack yml files & can use one file at a time for deploy/ rm etc. operations on stack.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `docker-compose`? Yes, it is perfectly OK to have multiple compose-files with different services. You can either

- Deploy those individually with `docker-compose stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.blaablaa.yml [stack]`
- Or if they have dependencies with each other or a common compose file that contains something every stack needs, you can do something like

  `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.stack1.yml config > docker-compose.stack.yml
  docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.stack.yml`

See also https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30127.

Comment: I just validated this in docker-compose & it works but we are running docker-swarm mode.